# Adding conditions to a UNION in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm not sure if what I'm looking to do is possible with a union, or if I need to use  a nested query and join of some sort.

```
select c1,c2 from t1
union
select c1,c2 from t2
// with some sort of condition where t1.c1 = t2.c1
```

Example:

```
t1
| 100 | regular |
| 200 | regular |
| 300 | regular |
| 400 | regular |

t2
| 100 | summer |
| 200 | summer |
| 500 | summer |
| 600 | summer |

Desired Result
| 100 | regular |
| 100 | summer  |
| 200 | regular |
| 200 | summer  |
```

I've tried something like:

```
select * from (select * from t1) as q1
inner join
    (select * from t2) as q2 on q1.c1 = q2.c1
```

But that joins the records into a single row like this:

```
| 100 | regular | 100 | summer |
| 200 | regular | 200 | summer |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
select c1, c2
  from t1
 where c1 in (select c1 from t2)
union all
select c1, c2
  from t2
 where c1 in (select c1 from t1)
```

Based on edit, try the below:

MySQL doesn't have the WITH clause which would allow you to refer to your t1 and t2 subs multiple times. You might want to create both t1 and t2 as a view in your database so that you can refer to them as t1 and t2 multiple times throughout a single query.

Even still, the query below honestly looks very bad and could probably be optimized a lot if we knew your database structure. Ie. a list of the tables, all columns on each table and their data type, a few example rows from each, and your expected result.

For instance in your t1 sub you have an outer join with with the LESSON table, but then you have criteria in your WHERE clause (lesson.dayofweek >= 0) which would naturally not allow for nulls, effectively turning your outer join into an inner join. Also you have subqueries that only check for the existence of studentid using criteria that would suggest several tables used don't actually need to be used to produce your desired result. However without knowing your database structure and some example data with an expected result it's hard to advise further.

Even still, I believe the below will probably get you what you want, just not optimally.

```
select *
  from (select distinct students.student_number as "StudentID",
                        concat(students.first_name, ' ', students.last_name) as "Student",

                        general_program_types.general_program_name as "Program Category",
                        program_inventory.program_code as "Program Code",
                        std_lesson.studio_name as "Studio",
                        concat(teachers.first_name, ' ', teachers.last_name) as "Teacher",

          from lesson_student
          left join lesson
            on lesson_student.lesson_id = lesson.lesson_id
          left join lesson_summer
            on lesson_student.lesson_id = lesson_summer.lesson_id

         inner join students
            on lesson_student.student_number = students.student_number
         inner join studio as std_primary
            on students.primary_location_id = std_primary.studio_id
         inner join studio as std_lesson
            on (lesson.studio_id = std_lesson.studio_id or
               lesson_summer.studio_id = std_lesson.studio_id)

         inner join teachers
            on (lesson.teacher_id = teachers.teacher_id or
               lesson_summer.teacher_id = teachers.teacher_id)
         inner join lesson_program
            on lesson_student.lesson_id = lesson_program.lesson_id
         inner join program_inventory
            on lesson_program.program_code_id =
               program_inventory.program_code_id
         inner join general_program_types
            on program_inventory.general_program_id =
               general_program_types.general_program_id

         inner join accounts
            on students.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = accounts.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
         inner join account_contacts
            on students.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = account_contacts.ACCOUNT_NUMBER

        /** NOTE: the WHERE condition is the only **/
        /** difference between subquery1 & subquery2 **/
         where lesson.dayofweek >= 0 and
         order by students.STUDENT_NUMBER) t1
 where StudentID in
       (select StudentID
          from (select distinct students.student_number as "StudentID",
                                concat(students.first_name,
                                       ' ',
                                       students.last_name) as "Student",

                                general_program_types.general_program_name as "Program Category",
                                program_inventory.program_code as "Program Code",
                                std_lesson.studio_name as "Studio",
                                concat(teachers.first_name,
                                       ' ',
                                       teachers.last_name) as "Teacher",

                  from lesson_student
                  left join lesson
                    on lesson_student.lesson_id = lesson.lesson_id
                  left join lesson_summer
                    on lesson_student.lesson_id = lesson_summer.lesson_id

                 inner join students
                    on lesson_student.student_number =
                       students.student_number
                 inner join studio as std_primary
                    on students.primary_location_id = std_primary.studio_id
                 inner join studio as std_lesson
                    on (lesson.studio_id = std_lesson.studio_id or
                       lesson_summer.studio_id = std_lesson.studio_id)

                 inner join teachers
                    on (lesson.teacher_id = teachers.teacher_id or
                       lesson_summer.teacher_id = teachers.teacher_id)
                 inner join lesson_program
                    on lesson_student.lesson_id = lesson_program.lesson_id
                 inner join program_inventory
                    on lesson_program.program_code_id =
                       program_inventory.program_code_id
                 inner join general_program_types
                    on program_inventory.general_program_id =
                       general_program_types.general_program_id

                 inner join accounts
                    on students.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = accounts.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
                 inner join account_contacts
                    on students.ACCOUNT_NUMBER =
                       account_contacts.ACCOUNT_NUMBER

                /** NOTE: the WHERE condition is the only **/
                /** difference between subquery1 & subquery2 **/
                 where lesson_summer.dayofweek >= 0
                 order by students.STUDENT_NUMBER) t2)
UNION ALL
select *
  from (select distinct students.student_number as "StudentID",
                        concat(students.first_name, ' ', students.last_name) as "Student",

                        general_program_types.general_program_name as "Program Category",
                        program_inventory.program_code as "Program Code",
                        std_lesson.studio_name as "Studio",
                        concat(teachers.first_name, ' ', teachers.last_name) as "Teacher",

          from lesson_student
          left join lesson
            on lesson_student.lesson_id = lesson.lesson_id
          left join lesson_summer
            on lesson_student.lesson_id = lesson_summer.lesson_id

         inner join students
            on lesson_student.student_number = students.student_number
         inner join studio as std_primary
            on students.primary_location_id = std_primary.studio_id
         inner join studio as std_lesson
            on (lesson.studio_id = std_lesson.studio_id or
               lesson_summer.studio_id = std_lesson.studio_id)

         inner join teachers
            on (lesson.teacher_id = teachers.teacher_id or
               lesson_summer.teacher_id = teachers.teacher_id)
         inner join lesson_program
            on lesson_student.lesson_id = lesson_program.lesson_id
         inner join program_inventory
            on lesson_program.program_code_id =
               program_inventory.program_code_id
         inner join general_program_types
            on program_inventory.general_program_id =
               general_program_types.general_program_id

         inner join accounts
            on students.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = accounts.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
         inner join account_contacts
            on students.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = account_contacts.ACCOUNT_NUMBER

        /** NOTE: the WHERE condition is the only **/
        /** difference between subquery1 & subquery2 **/
         where lesson_summer.dayofweek >= 0
         order by students.STUDENT_NUMBER) x
 where StudentID in
       (select StudentID
          from (select distinct students.student_number as "StudentID",
                                concat(students.first_name,
                                       ' ',
                                       students.last_name) as "Student",

                                general_program_types.general_program_name as "Program Category",
                                program_inventory.program_code as "Program Code",
                                std_lesson.studio_name as "Studio",
                                concat(teachers.first_name,
                                       ' ',
                                       teachers.last_name) as "Teacher",

                  from lesson_student
                  left join lesson
                    on lesson_student.lesson_id = lesson.lesson_id
                  left join lesson_summer
                    on lesson_student.lesson_id = lesson_summer.lesson_id

                 inner join students
                    on lesson_student.student_number =
                       students.student_number
                 inner join studio as std_primary
                    on students.primary_location_id = std_primary.studio_id
                 inner join studio as std_lesson
                    on (lesson.studio_id = std_lesson.studio_id or
                       lesson_summer.studio_id = std_lesson.studio_id)

                 inner join teachers
                    on (lesson.teacher_id = teachers.teacher_id or
                       lesson_summer.teacher_id = teachers.teacher_id)
                 inner join lesson_program
                    on lesson_student.lesson_id = lesson_program.lesson_id
                 inner join program_inventory
                    on lesson_program.program_code_id =
                       program_inventory.program_code_id
                 inner join general_program_types
                    on program_inventory.general_program_id =
                       general_program_types.general_program_id

                 inner join accounts
                    on students.ACCOUNT_NUMBER = accounts.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
                 inner join account_contacts
                    on students.ACCOUNT_NUMBER =
                       account_contacts.ACCOUNT_NUMBER

                /** NOTE: the WHERE condition is the only **/
                /** difference between subquery1 & subquery2 **/
                 where lesson.dayofweek >= 0 and
                 order by students.STUDENT_NUMBER) x);
```

Comment: I updated my question to include the sub-queries t1 & t2 are actually aliases to. When I tried you solution it tells me "Table <mydb>.t2 does not exist. I gather it is some sort of table alias scope issue. Does this make sense?

Comment: @Kevin replace t2 with whatever the name of the table is. In your example you referred to it as t2

Comment: t1 and t2 aren't tables in my db, they're aliases I created for my two subqueries.

Comment: If you modify your example to include the actual tables and your desired result I can change the answer.

Answer (score 0):

In order to compare values from two tables you need to do a join. The first way I see is to do 2 queries with inner join and union them:

```
select t1.* from t1
inner join t2 using (c1)
union
select t2.* from t1
inner join t2 using (c1)
```

However, we can do better: you can see that I use the exact same query up to which columns I select in the result set, that's a bit of a waste. If we could simply duplicate every records<sup>(1)</sup>? Well, we can:

```
select * from t1
inner join t2 using (c1)
cross join (
    select 0 as parity
    union
    select 1 as parity) dup
```

Now we have everything in double, with an extra column for parity, we just need to select either set of column on that:

```
-- broken query
select case parity when 
   0 then t1.*
   1 then t2.*
end from t1
inner join t2 using (c1)
cross join (
    select 0 as parity
    union
    select 1 as parity) dup
```

Unfortunately, the `case` expression does not allow to return several columns, thus we need to include the test for all of them. In your case, one column is enough:

```
select c1, case parity when 
   0 then t1.c2
   1 then t2.c2
end from t1
inner join t2 using (c1)
cross join (
    select 0 as parity
    union
    select 1 as parity) dup
order by c1
-- order by parity, c1
```

Use the commented out `order by` instead to get the result set for `t1` first, an then `t2`.

Caveat: code untested.

---

<sup>(1) There's this feature called CTE in ANSI SQL (99 I think)  which allows to factor out a common query and then reference it throughout the main query, but sadly mysql does not support it.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

An `UNION` is okay.

You want to run the same join **twice**. Except that the first time over you get the left side, and the second time the right side.

```
SELECT t1.* FROM t1 JOIN t2 USING (c1)
UNION
SELECT t2.* FROM t1 JOIN t2 USING (c1)
```

Of course, if at all possible, you could run a single query and save the left side in memory, display the right side, then enqueue the saved left side at end. It needs much more memory than a cursor, but runs the query in half the time (something less actually, due to disk and resource caching).

See [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b632/2) the sample SQLFiddle.